# handle dependency of model in database

Tags: flutter, dart, oop

I am writing a Flutter project with Firebase as database, and I have several model to be store in database, a controller to control upload/download.

There are some of the model that is dependent to another model, for example, a `ProfileModel` contains `name`, and a `MissionModel` contains `ownerName` which is depend on `name`.

I am now write it like below, passing controller to the model, and let it obtain whatever it need with the controller.

However, this approach seems to couple the controller and the model. Is there a way to decouple it?

```
abstract class DataModel<T extends DataModel> {
  T fromFirestore(Map data, Controller controller);
}

class ProfileModel extends DataModel<ProfileModel> {
  String name;
  ProfileModel(this.name);
  @override
  ProfileModel fromFirestore(Map data, Controller controller) {
    return ProfileModel(data['name']);
  }
}

class MissionModel extends DataModel<MissionModel> {
  String ownerName;
  MissionModel(this.ownerName);
  @override
  MissionModel fromFirestore(Map data, Controller controller) {
    return MissionModel(controller
        .downloadFromFirestore(ProfileModel('just an empty instance'))
        .name);
  }
}

class Controller {
  //has some attribute to communicate with Firebase
  T downloadFromFirestore<T extends DataModel<T>>(T specificType) {
    //call Firebase API to download data
    return specificType.fromFirestore(data, this);
  }
}
```